# A shape in XAML - how to draw this:

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

### I need to make this shape on a windows phone 8 using XAML:

[image: The hebrew is not important]

It is easy to make a rectangle with rounded corners, and the gray background also. But to make the top of the rectangle to be as shown seems very hard. Can someone give me a hint? It's been 2 years since I used XAML, and I am removeing the rust.

Comment: Windows Phone 8 doesn't use WPF. WPF is a desktop technology. Did you mean XAML?

Comment: Yes. I am sorry I didn't know that. It seems the same for me.

Comment: Hm, not sure if it is possible in wp8, but in WPF you would use a clip or opacity mask. Maybe wp8 allows something like that aswell.

Comment: Post the XAML you already got so we can work on it instead of having to write it all from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nah not really, it's actually pretty simple and there's multiple ways to accomplish the same effect. Here's an example.

```
<Grid Width="150" Height="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border CornerRadius="10,10,0,0">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.822,0.633" StartPoint="0.158,0.189">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF09CCF4" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF020CA7" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <TextBlock Text="Blah" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="White" CornerRadius="0,0,10,10"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Other Stuff" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

You can trade the `Border` 's that were used for `Rectangle`'s if you like, hope this helps.